# Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the error when transpiling Typescript with npm run build:

```
Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Index.ts

```
public init(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>, notifyOutputChanged: () => void, state: ComponentFramework.Dictionary, container:HTMLDivElement)
    {
        // the increment value defaults to 1 if no increment input is detected, or it is zero.
        this._incrementValue = 1;
        if(context.parameters.incrementValue != null){
            if(context.parameters.incrementValue.raw != 0){
                this._incrementValue = context.parameters.incrementValue.raw;
            }
        }
```

On this part:

```
this._incrementValue
```

Is there a way to avoid the compiler to complaint about dealing with nulls?

Comment: does using !== help? see [link](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html) or here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523650/4083037)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this statement

`this._incrementValue = context.parameters.incrementValue.raw;`

assignes the union type(number | null) to number type. Changing the type of the property _incrementValue to the same union type should calm the TS compiler. "Casting" **context.parameters.incrementValue.raw as number** might also do the trick. Good luck!

Comment: context.parameters.incrementValue.raw as number fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you need to also check `context.parameters.incrementValue.raw !== null` before assigning it to `this._incrementValue`;